Error MSB4018 The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly
Recently I installed VS2022 and VSC. I opened my projecct in VS2022 and Im getting this error Error MSB4018 The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly
If I open this project in VS2019 i get the same error (recently i pulled this project from GIT and wanted to work on him with VS2022). Other projects are working fine in VS2019.
Getting this all the time:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.WriteDepsFile(String depsFilePath)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskWithAssemblyResolveHooks.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Enteo.Lifocolor C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets    284
I tried the things from other topic The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly
Nothing works for me, i tried to delete bin and .vs, restart machine (im working on windows server machine), clean, rebuild, build
I pushed it to git, tried to pull to different path and open and its not working anyway (but my coworker when he pulls from git doesnt get this problem.
Do you have any ideas what i could do that could help me?

You could check the following steps.1.Ensure that the disk where your project is located is healthy and functioning properly.2.Verify that you have the necessary permissions to read and write to the project directory and its files. Make sure that your user account has full access to the project files.3.Sometimes, antivirus software can interfere with disk access and cause issues during the build process. Temporarily disable any antivirus software and see if the issue persists.4. Make sure that no other process or application is holding a lock on any files or directories within your project.

I had the similar problem with my Azure CI builds on self-hosted agent.
Previously I had .NET 6 projects, and after making them multi-targeting and specifying net6.0 target framework on build (dotnet build -f net6.0), I had the following error with some of them:
[error]/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(284,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '/__w/43/s/.../bin/Release/net6.0/Project.deps.json' because it is being used by another process.

Then I deleted all bin and obj dirs in the solution directory, and that helps.
But it is not suitable for me (automatic cached builds).
Then I removed target framework (-f net6.0) from the build options, and that solved my problem entirely.
Hope that will help you.
